# Unity - Spotlight turns off when not looking towards it

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting, light

I have 2 lights in the room. one is a point light, that ligts up the room, and the other is a spot light that points towards the lava to make the lava brighter.

here is a short video showing the problem:
https://i.gyazo.com/30d2118c3fbc6e2da91e02fdfa3c5d29.mp4

Comment: What's the render mode of the culled light?

Comment: point light: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/c43ea8c57cf5fe4419a0f99440537cba.png)

spotlight: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/43dc5fd27a12ed6e6fc2cc0e83d7ea57.png)[link]

Comment: You could try changing the render mode off auto, I don't remember what the other settings are but there should be something like "necessary" .

Comment: There is a limit to the number of pixel lights, generally really pretty low.

Comment: Increasing the number of pixel count did not work. I tried everything from 4 to 98 for the sake of testing, but made no difference. I also tried setting render mode to "important". This did unfortunately not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to necro post, i was looking for a solution to a slightly different problem. But, I think you just went about the lighting wrong. Your using a light that has to send a ray cast down, hit the ground, and generate light. Your player (hero) is the issue. When you stand under the light, even a small bit, the ray cast is hitting you.
Better option:
Use a self illuminating texture on the magma, or a point light closer to the magma, with a high intensity and low range. See this video for more options:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnG2gOKV9dw

Hope this helps